# old recyclerview stays as a background after rotation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I am using a recyclerview with mmvm+livedata+databinding. 
After each rotation, I can see the old items stuck behind as sort of a background.

I can see that the adapter has the right amount of items, and indeed the adapter only displays and scrolls the newest data. In the background however you can see the old list.

the code is pretty standard and simple - plain simple adatper/recyclervyew with data binding items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though you haven't posted any code, which is really unhelpful, I'm going to *assume* that you are displaying your `RecyclerView` inside a Fragment, and that in your Activity's onCreate, you have the following line.

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(frameLayout, fragment)
    .commit();
```

One of the nice things about FragmentManager is that it keeps your fragments even after you rotate the screen so that the content doesn't change. It does this whenever `savedInstanceState` is not null.

What this means is that if you just add your fragment with checking the saved state, it will get placed over the fragment that the manager saved, which is what you are doing. Taking advantage of this feature to maintain state takes a bit of coding effort however, and I can't help you with that since I do not know what your code looks like. So, the easiest soluion is to just change `add` to `replace`.

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(frameLayout, fragment)
    .commit();
```

This tells the manager "I don't care about saved state. If there was a fragment there before, just remove it before adding this one."

Comment: Thank you for the help! however, I found the problem. Apparently the issue was that the fragment container in the xml was FrameLayout. 
It turns out FrameLayout and RelativeLayout can be quite buggy when they act as fragment containers and one should use LinearLayout instead.

Comment: Fragments inside LinearLayouts? That... doesn't sound right, but if it works, ok.

Comment: Yep, I actually found that solution here on SO. It does sound strange and not right though..  :/

Comment: so turns out it is very problematic to use LinearLayout... cause then I am unable to add fragments to that container, only to replace.